# Building a pastebin app and can't to deserialize objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization

Building a Java project(java 19) with spring boot(3.1.3) and gradle(8.2).
Also use a Google Cloud Storage and when getting data I want to deserialize data in the object with SerializationUtils,but climbs out this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.pastebin.entity.Paste cannot be cast to class com.example.pastebin.entity.Paste (com.example.pastebin.entity.Paste is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.example.pastebin.entity.Paste is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @6ed949b0)
    at com.example.pastebin.services.PasteService.findAll(PasteService.java:46) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.pastebin.controllers.PasteController.allPastes(PasteController.java:35) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:10.1.12]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.26.1'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Paste Entity:

```
package com.example.pastebin.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Paste implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8591616427310310802L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "text", nullable = false)
    private String text;

    @Lob
    private byte[] bytes;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

    private LocalDateTime dateOfCreated;

    @PrePersist
    private void init() {
        this.dateOfCreated = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
package com.example.pastebin.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class PasteDTO {
    private String title;
    private String text;
    private String author;
}
```

Paste Service:

```
package com.example.pastebin.services;

import com.example.pastebin.dto.PasteDTO;
import com.example.pastebin.entity.Paste;
import com.example.pastebin.entity.PasteDetails;
import com.example.pastebin.entity.User;
import com.example.pastebin.mappers.PasteMapper;
import com.example.pastebin.repositories.PasteDetailsRepository;
import com.example.pastebin.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.google.api.gax.paging.Page;
import com.google.cloud.storage.*;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class PasteService {
    private final Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    private final Bucket bucket = storage.get("pastebin1");

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasteDetailsRepository pasteDetailsRepository;
    private final PasteMapper pasteMapper;

    public PasteService(UserRepository userRepository, PasteDetailsRepository pasteDetailsRepository, PasteMapper pasteMapper) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.pasteDetailsRepository = pasteDetailsRepository;
        this.pasteMapper = pasteMapper;
    }

    public List<PasteDTO> findAll() {
        List<PasteDTO> pastes = new ArrayList<>();
        Page<Blob> blobs = bucket.list();

        for (Blob blob : blobs.getValues()) {
            byte[] bytes = blob.getContent();

            if (SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes) == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The byte[] must not be null");
            }
error here ->   pastes.add(pasteMapper.fromPasteToDTO((Paste) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes)));
        }

        return pastes;
    }

    public void connectUserToPaste(String username, Paste paste) {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("User not found");
        } else {
            paste.setUser(user);
            user.getPastes().add(paste);
        }
    }

    public void saveText(PasteDTO pasteDTO, String username) {
        Paste paste = Paste.builder()
                .title(pasteDTO.getTitle())
                .text(pasteDTO.getText())
                .build();
        this.connectUserToPaste(username, paste);

        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("pastebin1", "paste_" + paste.getId());
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
        Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, SerializationUtils.serialize(paste));

        PasteDetails pasteDetails = PasteDetails.builder()
                .blobId(blobId)
                .bucket(blob.getBucket())
                .build();

        pasteDetailsRepository.save(pasteDetails);

        log.info("Saving new bin with title : {}", paste.getTitle());
    }

    public PasteDTO findPasteByTitle(String title) {
        Page<Blob> blobs = bucket.list();
        for (Blob blob : blobs.getValues()) {
            if (title.equals(blob.getName())) {
                PasteDTO pasteDTO = pasteMapper.fromPasteToDTO((Paste) SerializationUtils.deserialize(blob.getContent()));
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And Paste Controller:

```
package com.example.pastebin.controllers;

import com.example.pastebin.dto.PasteDTO;
import com.example.pastebin.mappers.PasteMapper;
import com.example.pastebin.repositories.PasteDetailsRepository;
import com.example.pastebin.services.PasteService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import java.security.Principal;

@Controller
public class PasteController {
    private final PasteService pasteService;

    public PasteController(PasteService pasteService) {
        this.pasteService = pasteService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/add_paste")
    public String addBinPage() {
        return "home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add_paste")
    public String addBin(PasteDTO pasteDTO, Principal principal) {
        pasteService.saveText(pasteDTO, principal.getName());
        return "redirect:/pastes";
    }

    @GetMapping("pastes")
    public String allPastes(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("pastes", pasteService.findAll());
        return "pastes";
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.